# How can I reduce Mongo db by averaging out old data

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have a mongodb for measurements which has a document per measurements. Each doc looks like:

```
{
 timestamp : 123
 value     : 123
 meta1     : something
 meta2     : something
}
```

I get measurements from a number of sources every second, and so the db gets quite large, quickly. I'm interested in keeping the recent information at the frequency it was read in, but older data, i would like to average out periodically to save space, and make the db a bit quicker.

1.Whats the best approach in mongo?

2.Is there a better db for this, considering that the schema is different for different measurements, and a fixed format wouldn't work very well. RRD is also not an option as i need the dynamic query abilities.?

Answer (score 4):

**1. Whats the best approach in mongo?**
  Use [capped collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections) for use cases such as logging. Another approach is to create a 'background process' that will be move old data from collection.

**2.Is there a better db for this, considering that the schema is different for different measurements, and a fixed format wouldn't work very well. RRD is also not an option as i need the dynamic query abilities.?** 
 Mongodb is a good fit here.

**Update:**
Another approch is to store each data item twice: First in capped collection(and use this collection for quering). And create another collection(or even another logdb) just for logging your events.

Comment: +1 for capped collections as a potential, but prob background process in OP's case. Plus MongoDB being a good fit

Comment: capped collections are great, but I don't think they will suit what i need. I would like to keep data, but reduce it by averaging (for example) the values from 3 documents into a single document.

Comment: Possible two ways: 1. Background process that remove old data. 2. Store data twice in capped collection and in log collection.

Comment: @Duncan: if you need averaging of old data and then removal of that old data, it's probably worth writing a MapReduce for that averaging, then having the background process first fire that MapReduce before removing the old data. So the ability to do a MapReduce indicates that MongoDB is a good choice here.

Comment: You can likely leverage the new Mongodb 1.8 MapReduce features for the reduction side of things. I did a writeup a few weeks ago that covers them : http://blog.evilmonkeylabs.com/2011/01/27/MongoDB-1_8-MapReduce/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the input.

I think I'm going to try out using buckets for different timeframes. So, i'll create 3 stores corresponding to say 1sec, 1min, 15min, and then manage the aggregation through a manual job running every so often which will compact/average out the values, delete of stuff that's not needed, etc...

Comment: Generally speaking this is the easiest way to go. Build one document per large time range (hour/day) and then $push / $inc data into that document. It's easier to expire old data this way and frankly it's much easier to query (return 24 hourly documents, instead of 86400 "secondly" documents). It's also space efficient as you avoid repeating data. FYI, to save even more space, look at shrinking your field names. Instead of "timestamp" use "ts", instead of "value" use "v", etc.

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm not sure about the best approach but a simple one would be to have a cron job that would remove all the documents older than a given timestamp (`your_time = now - some_time`).

   `db.docs.remove({ timestamp : {'$lte' : your_time}})`
2. Given that you need a schemaless database that allows you to perform dynamic queries, mondogb seems to be a good fit.

Comment: As in above comment, i'd like to average, say 3 docs, into 1 new doc, and not remove them entirely. I think a cron job would definately be the way forward (or something similar).

Comment: What problems here? just create some process and configure it to run daily or as you wish and merge/delete/move/update your collection.

Comment: @Duncan ok, so the cron job would calculate the averaged doc (map/reduce), add it to the collection and remove the docs used in the calculation.